# Как реализовать undo, redo в виджете Text tkinter python?

Tags: python, tkinter, textview

У меня есть код:

```py
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
def undo():
    txt.edit_undo()
def redo():
    txt.edit_redo()
txt = ScrolledText()
txt.pack(expand = True, fill = 'both')
```

Но при вызове этих функций, ничего не изменяется. Помогите найти решение. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы всё работало нужно добавить в текстовый виджет :

```
undo=True
```

В вашем случае:

```
from tkinter.scrolledtext import *
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
def undo():
    txt.edit_undo()
def redo():
    txt.edit_redo()
button_undo=Button(root, command=undo,text="undo")
button_redo=Button(root, command=redo,text="redo")
button_undo.pack()
button_redo.pack()
txt = ScrolledText(root,undo=True)
txt.pack(expand = True, fill=BOTH)
root.mainloop()
```